# In C, I am having trouble tracing a code and not sure how the value is being computed?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am tracing a code but I don't understand how the values are being calculated. My question is on the comments beside the code.

I am tracing code and I understand all the parts except 2. I posted those 2 part below. I will be really glad if someone could help me.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int function1(int *m, int n)
{
    *m = *m + n;
    return(*m);
}
int function2(int n, int *m)
{
    n = *m + 2;
    return(n);
}
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 3;
    int *xptr = &x,*yptr = &y;      
    x = 1; y = 3;
    y = function1(xptr,x);
    printf("x = %d, Y = %d\n",x,y);//x=2 but why? shouldn't it be x=1? y=2          
    x = 1; y = 3;
    x = function1(yptr,function2(2,yptr));
    printf("x = %d, y = %d\n",x,y);//x=8 y=8 but why? shouldn't y=3?        
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pass pointers to function which modify the pointee.

Comment: Have you studied pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, inside function1:

```
int function1(int *m, int n) {
    *m = *m + n;
    return(*m);
}                 /* 
...                */
y = function1(xptr,x);
```

- `n` holds a copy of the value of `x`,
- `m` holds a copy of the value of `xptr`, which is the address of `x`.
- `*m` refers to the contents of the address held by `m`
- ...`*m = *m + n`

That's 'assign to the contents of the address of `x`: the contents of the address of `x`, plus the value of `x`'.

The contents of the address of `x` (aka it's value) is 1.  So we assign 1 + 1 to the contents of address holding the value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first `printf`, `x == 2` because when calling `function1` the first time `*m` is a pointer to `x`, so you assign to the location pointed by `m` (that is the location of `x`), `*m + n == x + x == 1 + 1 == 2`.

In the second `printf`, `y == 8` because in `function2` you return its value incremented by 2 (so `3 + 2 == 5`) but without updating `y`, so in `function1` you sum the resulting value of `function2` to the old value of `y` (`3 + 5 == 8`). `function1` return also that value, so also `x == 8`.